# kafka.consumer.fetcher.ConsumerRecord access to topic name

Tags: python, kafka-python

I'm trying to process a message received from akafka consumer

```
for message in self.consumer:
        try:
            self.process_message(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

When I try to read topic name from ConsumerRecord

```
 def process_message(self, message: ConsumerRecord):

    timestamp = message.timestamp
    message = message.value
    try:
        topic = message.topic
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"----{e}")
```

I received this error:

> 'bytes' object has no attribute 'topic'